# Crystal Report not sorting the group field in ascending order as it is set up to do

Tags: crystal-reports, grouping, suppress

I have a report with three groups:

1. Project
2. RFI
3. Status

I am conditionally suppressing groups 2 and 3. In each suppress formula section respectively, it says

{?Sort}="RFI" (or "Status")

It does the suppression correctly. However, when it is sorted by Status, the status field is not in ascending order. Does anyone know hwy this would happen?

I can't choose a table in the Group Sort Order Formula either:
[image: I can't choose a table in the Group Sort Order Formula either:]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppressing report sections will have no bearing on how the records are sorted. A report will always have its records sorted from the outer-most group field to the inner-most group field. In your report, the records will first be sorted by "Project", then by "RFI", and finally by "Status" regardless of what you are or are not suppressing.

If you want to choose which field to sort the report by via a parameter, then you should create a formula field and sort by *that* instead. So something like: `if {?Sort}="RFI" then {table.RFI} else {table.Status}` but you'll need to get rid of your RFI and Status groups first.

Comment: The way you've explained it makes perfect sense. The report is first being grouped by RFI, meaning it is sorted that way. 

Trying to add that formula to the Group Sort Order Formula is not working as I cannot pick a table at all. I only have parameters and formulas to choose from. I don't think I've ever run into this before. Any ideas?

Please see the screenshot I added to my question regarding the group sort order formula.

Comment: You want the Record Sort Order, not the Group Sort Order. The Group Sort Order controls _how_ groups are sorted, not _what_ is sorted. Notice that your only options for the Group Sort Order formula are ascending, descending, or original.

Comment: Ok, I created the following formula and did a Record Sort based on it:
>IF {?Sort}="RFI" 
>THEN {PMRI.RFI}
>ELSE
>IF {?Sort}="Status"
>THEN
>{PMRI.Status}

Then, I use the Select Expert, refer to that formula (@Sort) and say "is equal to {?Sort}" and my report stops working.

Comment: The Select Expert has nothing to do with sorting the records, either. You want the Record Sort Expert ("Report" menu → "Record Sort Expert")

Comment: I had that already. I'm not sure what I changed, but it's working now. Thanks Ryan!